# Move Visual Studio Code Panel from right to bottom

Tags: visual-studio-code

I move Visual Studio Code's workbench Panel to the right

[image: VS Code with panel on right]

Now I cannot seem to move it to the bottom. Dragging Terminal/Problem to the bottom does not work. I have also ensure in `User Settings` there is this setting

```
"workbench.panel.defaultLocation": "bottom"
```

After restarting VS Code, the Panel is still on the right.

Answer (score 50):

I was stuck on this for a bit as well.

Make the Terminal panel bigger and you'll see the icon to move it back to the bottom.

Comment: Thank you. I was stuck with this issue. It seems that there should be a place to expand buttons not shown because small size...

Comment: Thanks but wow that's a poor and non-intuitive design choice. You'd think at least some kind of over state to show there are hidden icons.

Comment: In my case for version 1.30.2 you have to right click the terminal tab and select "Move Panel to Bottom".

Comment: Same in version 1.31.1. no icon for "Move panel to bottom" but resides in right click menu

Answer (score 11):

The "panel position button" has been moved to context menu since v1.29. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53302863/914967